# How to override a website's template's stylesheet by CKEditor 4.0's default one

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, stylesheet

When I incorporate CKEditor 4.0 with an HTML page without any styles or stylesheet associated, the editor looks fine when it comes to exhibiting bullets and numbers.

However, when I apply the template's stylesheet/CSS, the integrated CKEditor component starts not displaying bullets and numbers properly. I meant it displays the site's stylesheet's bullets which is totally not designated for that context. For e.g. the bullets shows up as a small picture at the right side of each text entry. Or nothing shows up for 1, 2, 3, etc.

How can I make the CKEditor not use the site's stylesheet, but use its own instead. The code snippet looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>FAQ</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/themes/construct/stylesheets/style.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/themes/construct/stylesheets/responsive.css"> 
<script src="~/Content/themes/construct/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Content/themes/construct/scripts/jquery.simpleFAQ-0.7.min.js"></script>  
<script src="~/Content/themes/construct/scripts/js_func.js"></script>
<script src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#faq').simpleFAQ();
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wraper">
 <header class="header">
 </header>
</div> 

 <!-- /top_title -->
 <!-- /faq_list -->
 <div class="faq_list">
  <ul class="filter">
   <li class="active all"><a href="#all">All</a></li>
   <li class="business"><a href="#business">Business</a></li>
   <li class="technical"><a href="#technical">Technical</a></li>
   <li class="miscellaneous"><a href="#miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="faq">
    @foreach (var entry in Model.MyList)
    {
    <li class="all business">
        <p class="question">
            @entry.Question
        </p>
        @foreach (var newEntry in entry.List2)
        {            
            <div class="answer" id="editable" contenteditable="true">
                <h1>@newEntry.Header</h1>
                <p>@newEntry.Answer</p>
            </div>

            }
    </li>
        }
  </ul>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks for the help.
Arash

Answer (score 0):

The best way to overwrite the style sheet are..

1. Copy the same classes into a new file and link this file after the default site. Ex.
   default:

   .class1 {font: normal 12px Arial;}

overwrite

```
.class1 {font: bold 12px Arial;}
```

2.. Follow the previous process and mark attributes as !important. Ex..

default:

```
.class1 {font: normal 12px Arial;padding:10px;}
```

overwrite:

```
.class1 {font: normal 12px Arial;padding-left:10px !important;}
```